# Clear explanation of dummy variable trap

Tags: regression, dataset, categorical-encoding, dummy-variable-trap

I have a confusion in multiple regression about dummy variable trap, so far I had seen tutorials explaining about dummy variable trap and multicollinearity but I'm unable to understand it fully.

Comment: I can't see that you have a new question here. Search the forum for "dummy variable trap". I've specified a good thread as duplicated, which has more general pertinence, which is here a good thing.

Comment: @NickCox That's not of my understanding level I'm a beginner and want a simple way to get the concept right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you have a binary variable, like sex. You create two dummy variables to reflect that in your model. Let's say you have six individuals $(M,F,F,M,M,F)$. Your dummy variables look like:

- $X_1=(0,1,1,0,0,1)$
- $X_2=(1,0,0,1,1,0)$

But now $X_{i1}+X_{i2} = 1$ for every possible $i$ so you have a case of perfect multicolinearity. The model will not distinguish between an effect caused by a high $X_1$ or a low $X_2$ and vice-versa.

The way to avoid this trap is to get rid of one of those variables. but this implies taking one of the groups as a "reference" which is kind of an arbitraty choice.

More importantly, when considering multiple factors simultaneously, it may be the case that some of the dummy variables reach perfect multicolinearity due to the way your individuals are distributed among the groups.

Imagine, for example, you also have data like "taller than 170 cm/shorter than 170 cm" and you get $(T,S,S,T,T,S)$ (which is not rare to expect) You will be facing a similar problem to that we had when considering $X_1$ and $X_2$

Comment: But let say I have 3 categorical variables ${X_{1}, X_{2} , X_{3} }$ such that if we neglect $X_{3}$ we get a equation that for some $i$ and $j$ , $X_{i1}+X_{i2}=X_{j1}+X_{j2}$ then isn't  this called collinearity too? We'll then have to neglect another variable I guess.

Comment: No. That's just like having an 18-year old who weights 80 kilos and a 28-year old who weights 70. Linear regression can handle that without any problem (if it couldn't, linear regression would be pretty much useless)

Comment: I mean to say that if we have 3 variables and even after neglecting one we get the same results as perfect collinearity then do we have to remove more variables?

Comment: @SahilSilare Yes! We must remove variables until multicolinearity disappears, but multicolinearity appears when the equality you showed is true for all possible $i$ and $i=j$ and, not just when there are some $i$ and $j$ that make it true

Comment: Okay I got it. Thanks alot!

Comment: This answer might be made clearer by explicitly pointing out it is assuming a *constant* term is included in the regression: only in this way can we understand your examples of collinearity.  This would also make it apparent there is another way to eliminate the collinearity: remove the constant term.  This solves the problem of designating a reference class, too.

Comment: @whuber That is true. However, in most regression models we will also have additional continuous regressors which will make the presence of the constante term quite convenient. Anyway feel free to add your point if you think it makes more good than harm

Comment: Yes, that's an important consideration (and I figured you had it in mind).  As moderator I'm uninterested in adding to or modifying your post, but on behalf of all readers, present and future, I am concerned that it be clear and accurate.  If you understand that as the motivation underlying my comments, you will know what to do and I hope you will find such comments, to the extent any more need to be made, to be helpful and unobjectionable.

Comment: @whuber Removing the constant is an alternative way isn't it?

Comment: Sahil Yes, that's right, assuming--as David has cautioned in a comment--you have only one categorical regressor in the model.